# kCFBundleNameKey returning null when project have multiple targets

Tags: iphone, xcode, null, bundle, nsbundle

im trying to get the short name of the bundle by using kCFBundleNameKey

```
NSString *shortBundleName=[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
        objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *) kCFBundleNameKey];
```

its working fine but when I have multiple targets for some reason its returning null, is there a work around ?

getting the bundle is working fine:

> NSString *fullBundleName=[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *) kCFBundleIdentifierKey];

Answer (score 0):

CoreFoundation/CFBundle.h:

```
CF_EXPORT
const CFStringRef kCFBundleNameKey;
/* The human-readable name of the bundle.  
This key is often found in the InfoPlist.strings 
since it is usually localized. */
```

So, you should watch your target info.plist